# php - using curl to consume this web service

Tags: php, web-services, curl, asmx

I saw this post on consuming a web service using CURL: [Consume WebService with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379339/consume-webservice-with-php)

and I was trying to follow it, but haven't had luck. I uploaded a photo of the web service I'm trying to access. How would I formulate my request given the example below, assuming the URL was:

https://site.com/Spark/SparkService.asmx?op=InsertConsumer

[image]

I attempted this, but it just returns a blank page:

```
 $url = 'https://xxx.com/Spark/SparkService.asmx?op=InsertConsumer?NameFirst=Joe&NameLast=Schmoe&PostalCode=55555&EmailAddress=joe@schmoe.com&SurveyQuestionId=76&SurveyQuestionResponseId=1139';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $xmlobj = simplexml_load_string($result);
    print_r($xmlobj);
```

Comment: almost-but-not-quite-dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326589/php-how-to-make-a-proxy-for-a-web-service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really, you should probably look at the [SOAP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php). If it is not available or for some reason you must use cURL, here is a basic framework:

```
<?php

  // The URL to POST to
  $url = "http://www.mysoapservice.com/";

  // The value for the SOAPAction: header
  $action = "My.Soap.Action";

  // Get the SOAP data into a string, I am using HEREDOC syntax
  // but how you do this is irrelevant, the point is just get the
  // body of the request into a string
  $mySOAP = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope>
  <!-- SOAP goes here, irrelevant so wont bother writing it out -->
</soap:Envelope>
EOD;

  // The HTTP headers for the request (based on image above)
  $headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($mySOAP),
    'SOAPAction: '.$action
  );

  // Build the cURL session
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $mySOAP);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

  // Send the request and check the response
  if (($result = curl_exec($ch)) === FALSE) {
    die('cURL error: '.curl_error($ch)."<br />\n");
  } else {
    echo "Success!<br />\n";
  }
  curl_close($ch);

  // Handle the response from a successful request
  $xmlobj = simplexml_load_string($result);
  var_dump($xmlobj);

?>
```

Comment: what do you mean in your comment - the soap is irrelevant? And why is using the SOAP extension better?

Comment: Well I'm assuming you can generate the XML yourself - it's not really any different from generating HTML - and you need to know how to send it to the server, which is what the above illustrates. The reason I would say that using the SOAP extension would be better is because it is a framework specially designed for handling this specific task and will help to catch any errors and fill in the gaps for you. To be honest, I hate SOAP, I think it is a nightmare to work with in general. As a rule of thumb, if there is an extension for the task you are working on, it's probably the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

The service requires you to do a POST, and you're doing a GET (curl's default for HTTP urls) instead. Add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST);
```

and add some error handling:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best answer because using this once you need to login then
get some data from webservices(third party site data).

```
$tmp_fname = tempnam("/tmp", "COOKIE"); //create temporary cookie file

$post = array(
    'username=abc@gmail.com',
    'password=123456' 
); 

$post = implode('&', $post); 

//login with username and password
$curl_handle = curl_init ("http://www.example.com/login");

//create cookie session 
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmp_fname);  

curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 

$output = curl_exec ($curl_handle);

//Get events data after login 
$curl_handle = curl_init ("http://www.example.com/events");  

curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmp_fname); 

curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$output = curl_exec ($curl_handle);

//Convert json format to array
$data = json_decode($output); 

echo "Output : <br> <pre>";

   print_r($data);

echo "</pre>";
```